# Dynamic inventory groups from ansible plugin: nmap

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory, nmap

I'm trying to use the [nmap plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/nmap.html) in ansible to create a dynamic inventory, and then group things that the plugin returns. Unfortunately, I'm missing something, because I can't seem to get a group to be created.
In this scenario, I have a couple hosts named unknownxxxxxxxx that I would like to group.

```
plugin: nmap
strict: false
address: 10.0.1.0/24   
ports: no
groups:
  unknown: "'unknown' in hostname"
```

I run my plugin - 
`ansible-inventory -i nmap.yml --export --output=inv --list`

but the return is always the same...

By now, I've resorted to guessing possible var names

> host, hosts, hostnames, hostname, inventory_hostname, hostvars, host.fqdn, and the list goes on and on...

I'm obviously missing something basic, but I can't seem to find anything via search that has yielded any results.

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong with jinja?

Perhaps I need to use `compose:` and `keyed_groups:` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm obviously missing something basic...

I'm not sure that you are. I agree that according to the documentation the `nmap` plugin is supposed to work the way you're trying to use it, but like you I'm not able to get the `groups` or `compose` keys to work as described.

Fortunately, we can work around that problem by directly using the `constructed` inventory plugin.

We'll need to use an inventory directory, rather than an inventory *file*, since we need multiple inventory files. We'll put the following into our `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
inventory = inventory
```

And then we'll create a directory `inventory`, into which we'll place two files. First, we'll put your `nmap` inventory in `inventory/10nmap.yml`. It will look like this:

```
plugin: nmap
strict: false
address: 10.0.1.0/24   
ports: false
```

And then we'll put the configuration for the `constructed` plugin to `inventory/20constructed.yml`:

```
plugin: constructed
strict: False

groups:
  unknown: "'unknown' in inventory_hostname"
```

We've named the file `10nmap.yml` and `20constructed.yml` because we need to ensure that the `constructed` plugin runs after the `nmap` plugin (also, we're checking against `inventory_hostname` here because that's the canonical name of a host in your Ansible inventory).

---

With all this in place, you should see the behavior you're looking for: hosts with `unknown` in the `inventory_hostname` variable will end up in the `unknown` group.

Comment: I'm suspicious that this may be similar to bug [#48833](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/48833), which I encountered a couple of years ago in the openstack inventory plugin. I'll probably take a closer look this weekend.

Comment: Liked your answer. I managed to add groups using `keyed_groups` for my ec2 instances sometimes back.

Comment: Thank you @larsks - Glad to hear that I wasn't going insane... implemented your updates, and a short `ansible-inventory -i inventory --export --output=inv --list` later, I have the output that I'm looking to get. Now if only the documentation or operation of the plugin were accurate, I might have saved a hand-full of hair ;)

Comment: Thank you for this.  Ansible is great but if you need to manage hosts via their MAC address, then Ansible is a disappointment on multiple fronts. Inventory via MAC should be built-in. But since it's Community, Ansible should be requiring multiple working examples and test cases.  I was looking for this answer 2 years ago; I'm glad I re-searched because my problem remained.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `groups` apply only to attributes that the plugin returns, so you should be looking at its output.

For example, running `ansible-inventory -i nmap-inventory.yml --list` with

```yaml
---
plugin: nmap
address: 192.168.122.0/24
strict: false
ipv4: yes
ports: yes
sudo: true
groups:
  without_hostname: "'192.168.122' in name"
  with_ssh: "ports | selectattr('service', 'equalto', 'ssh')"
```

produces

```json
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "192.168.122.102": {
                "ip": "192.168.122.102",
                "name": "192.168.122.102",
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "port": "22",
                        "protocol": "tcp",
                        "service": "ssh",
                        "state": "open"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "192.168.122.204": {
                "ip": "192.168.122.204",
                "name": "192.168.122.204",
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "port": "22",
                        "protocol": "tcp",
                        "service": "ssh",
                        "state": "open"
                    },
                    {
                        "port": "8080",
                        "protocol": "tcp",
                        "service": "http",
                        "state": "open"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "fedora": {
                "ip": "192.168.122.1",
                "name": "fedora",
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "port": "53",
                        "protocol": "tcp",
                        "service": "domain",
                        "state": "open"
                    },
                    {
                        "port": "6000",
                        "protocol": "tcp",
                        "service": "X11",
                        "state": "open"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped",
            "with_ssh",
            "without_hostname"
        ]
    },
    "ungrouped": {
        "hosts": [
            "fedora"
        ]
    },
    "with_ssh": {
        "hosts": [
            "192.168.122.102",
            "192.168.122.204"
        ]
    },
    "without_hostname": {
        "hosts": [
            "192.168.122.102",
            "192.168.122.204"
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using `name` and `ports` because the entries have these attributes. I could've also used `ip`.

To further clarify the point, when I run the plugin with `ports: no`, the `with_ssh` grouping filter doesn't produce anything because there are no ports in the output.

```json
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "192.168.122.102": {
                "ip": "192.168.122.102",
                "name": "192.168.122.102"
            },
            "192.168.122.204": {
                "ip": "192.168.122.204",
                "name": "192.168.122.204"
            },
            "fedora": {
                "ip": "192.168.122.1",
                "name": "fedora"
            }
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped",
            "without_hostname"
        ]
    },
    "ungrouped": {
        "hosts": [
            "fedora"
        ]
    },
    "without_hostname": {
        "hosts": [
            "192.168.122.102",
            "192.168.122.204"
        ]
    }
}
```